# using javascript with css?

Tags: javascript, css

when i did click text input, i want to change input background color but with javascript.

I know with css.

I want for example.

```
<form action="" name="abc" method="post">
<input name="abc" id="name" type="text"/>
<input name="yusuf" type="text"/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

How can i select element name as name with javascript?

I want similar:

```
 <script>
document.getElementById("name").style = "background-color:red";
</script>
```

I want to write css code but direct. Shortly how can i reach style="" parameters?

Comment: better to use jquery lib, than pure js

Comment: sorry. i did find. document.getElementById("name").setAttribute("style",'background:red;');
@Marek Sebera. Thanks for proposal. I know jquery but i want to learn with javascript.

Comment: have you thought about using jQuery, MooTools or Prototype? It makes this sort of stuff really easy.

Comment: thanks fro proposal.. @gargantaun..

Comment: Check out my jQuery solution below, with working sample.  Another question would be: what's the reason for this behavior?  Are you doing some kind of validation?  If so, jQuery validate is a very complete solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for the [`style` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.style):

```
document.getElementById("name").style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

You can also set the `className` property to apply an existing CSS class to the element.

Answer (score 2):

Is jQuery an option?  You can try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var toggleRed = function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('red');
    };
    $('input[type=text]').focus(toggleRed);
    $('input[type=text]').blur(toggleRed);
});
```

And then define this in your CSS:

```
input.red { background-color: Red; color: White; }
```

Check out the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/V5qJp/